# Facebook connection crashes application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, exc-bad-access

I have fbconnection in my application it works fine but when i logout and re login; this is the place that the app crashes. This is the FBSession.m file. I need help with these i google it search but can't find anything usefull. Anybody understand or know the solution?Thanks for helping.

```
- (BOOL)resume {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
FBUID uid = [[defaults objectForKey:@"FBUserId"] longLongValue];
if (uid) {
    NSDate* expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBSessionExpires"];
    if (!expirationDate || [expirationDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
        _uid = uid;
        _sessionKey = [[defaults stringForKey:@"FBSessionKey"] copy];
        _sessionSecret = [[defaults stringForKey:@"FBSessionSecret"] copy];
        _expirationDate = [expirationDate retain];

        for (id<FBSessionDelegate> delegate in _delegates) {
            [delegate session:self didLogin:_uid];// This is the place that gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
return NO;
}
```

Edit:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

static NSString* kApiKey = @"605a4eee24bc4018210207cd152aaf0e";
static NSString* kApiSecret = @"4057291afc9430895461774a43881751";
_session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];

// Load a previous session from disk if available.  Note this will call session:didLogin if a valid session exists.
[_session resume];
NSLog(@"resume");
}
```

this is the place i set delegate

Comment: put a stack trace / error message, or it will be hard to figure what's going on... And "John Doe - 1 point" won't likely help making people want to spend time on this. Good luck :)

Comment: @vincent g how can i put stack trace? exc bad access didnt give any error msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search your project and find all files that your are putting into the delegates. From all these file's dealloc methods, remove them from the _delegates.

Most likely it's crashing because your delegate object (which could be a viewController that was popped earlier) is released and the _delegates array contains a hanging pointer to it.

Comment: thanks @Ved for answer i check all the delegates and dealloc all i guess i have to find another way to make it or i just miss it.

Comment: well i miss it :) checked twice and now it isn't crashing hmm thanks mate

Comment: You are welcome, checkout ios 5 SDK Automatic Reference Counting. The __weak specifier sets a pointer to nil when the object is released.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are setting the session's delegate to an object which is getting released. (If you show us the code near where you set the delegate, we can look at exactly what's wrong.)

Comment: you can check now mate this is the place i set delegate

Comment: Still hard to tell what's wrong... Is it possible your view controller is getting released somewhere else?

Comment: if u want i can post all of my code but it take a lot of space and time for u to check mate :( hmm it is modal view controller and when the user tab button it pop's after the pop action complete i want the post to wall appears.

Comment: Make sure you remove the delegate in `viewDidUnload`, I think that might fix it.

Comment: i ll try and report back mate

Comment: i set the delegate to nil but it still gives the same error and crashes